# Asymptotes of the integral curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

One of the first tasks in differential equation problem book. Obviously that, it’s separable equation, but integrals can’t be computed. The task is to proof that integral curve have two assymptoties[image: l]

Comment: Maple gives a solution in implicit form: $$-y \left( x \right) 
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}({\frac{1}{3}},{\frac{1}{2}};\,{\frac{3}{2}};\,- \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2})}
+\sqrt [3]{ \left( {x}^{4}+1 \right) ^{-1}}\sqrt [3]{{x}^{4}+1}x
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}({\frac{1}{4}},{\frac{1}{3}};\,{\frac{5}{4}};\,-{x}^{4})}
+{\it c1}=0
$$ where $_2F_1$ is hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that  an asymptote exists $y=ax+b$ with $a\neq 0$.

For $x\to\infty$ in this case $y'\to a$ while $y'\sim \sqrt[3]{\frac{y^2}{x^4}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2}{x^2}}\to 0$ . This is contradictory, thus the supposition is false.

Consequence: If an asymptote exists it can only be an horizontal asymptote $y=c_1$ or a vertical asymptote $x=c_2$.

Suppose that an horizontal asymptote exists : $y=c_1$

For $x\to\infty$ in this case $y'\sim \sqrt[3]{\frac{c_1^2+1}{x^4}}\to 0$ which satisfies $y'=\frac{dc_1}{dx}=0$ .

Conclusion : $y=c_1$ is an asymptote.

Suppose that an horizontal asymptote exists : $x=c_2$

For $y\to\infty$ in this case $x'\sim \sqrt[3]{\frac{c_2^4+1}{y^2}}\to 0$ which satisfies $x'=\frac{dc_2}{dy}=0$ .

Conclusion : $x=c_2$ is an asymptote.

Thus they are two asymptotes, one horizontal and the other vertical.

$c_1$ and $c_2$ depend on some boundary condition not specified in the wording of the problem.

Comment: Those are not sufficient conditions though. Otherwise it would imply that a solution of $y' = 1/x$ has a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Do you mean the function $y = c_1$? I'm saying your proof also proves that $y = c_1$ is an asymptote for solutions of $y' = 1/x$: $y' = 1/x \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$, which satisfies $dc_1/dx = 0$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I will correct my comment.

Comment: @ Maxim. In my answer it is not said that $y′=0$ IMPLIES an horizontal asymptote. It is checked that, the function $y=c1$ satisfies the ODE for $x\to\infty$. Never $y′=0$ is used to prove that $y=c_1$ is an asymptote. On the contrary it is proved that $y=c_1$ is an asymptote in this particular case (of course not in all cases). One must not confuse cheking and implying

Comment: You don't understand the proof. Again I don't need $y'=0$ for the poof. I directly pove that $y=c_1$ is solution of the ODE for $x\to\infty$ which proves that $y=c_1$ is an asymptote. To compare with your example one cannot prove that $y=c_1\neq 0$ is solution of $y'=1/x$ . Your conter-example is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Separation of variables will work:
$$f(y) = \int_{y_0}^y \frac {d\tau} {(\tau^2 + 1)^{1/3}} =
\int_{x_0}^x \frac {d\tau} {(\tau^4 + 1)^{1/3}} = g(x).$$
Since $f(y)$ is strictly increasing with image $\mathbb R$, the domain of the solution $y(x) = f^{-1}(g(x))$ is $\mathbb R$. Since $g(x)$ has finite limits at $\pm \infty$, the limits of $y(x)$ are also finite.

Comment: Note that $f'$ is non-zero, the limits $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} g(x)$ are different, and the solution for a given IC is unique.